# Configuring TileCache on Windows and Linux

Tags: python, mapserver, tilecache, mapfile, mapcache

I want to do tile caching for MapServer map files by using TileCache application. For this I have installed Python 2.7 and TileCache 2.11 and applied the following sequence of steps:

1. Extracted TileCache-2.11 tar file to my apache web directory into a folder tilecache
   Changed Disk Cache location in tilecache.cfg to my local folder
2. Replaced name, srs, url with my map file in place of basic layer
3. tested in browser using the url http://localhost:8088/tilecache/tilecache.cgi?LAYERS=APdem&&SERVICE=WMS&FORMAT=image/png&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=-180,-90,0,90

But i'm getting tilecache.cfg python code in the browser as:

```
  from TileCache import Service, cgiHandler, cfgfiles
if __name__ == '__main__':
    svc = Service.load("tilecache.cfg")
    cgiHandler(svc)
```

Is there any step missed in my process or what went wrong?
In Linux the apache httpd.conf file is as follows

```
 ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/tilecache>
     AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
     Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory /var/www/tilecache-2.11>
     AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
     Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>
# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">    
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>
<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
EnableSendfile on
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

the tilecache.cfg file is as follows

```
[cache]
type=Disk
base=/var/www/tilecache
[basic]
type=WMS
url=http://labs.metacarta.com/wms/vmap0
extension=png
[apdem]
type=WMS
url=https://test.com/mapserver/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=RMapFiles/apdem.map
extension=png
srs=EPSG:4326
layers=apdem
```

I have changed working directory in apache from html to cgi-bin the following error is appearing
I extracted the tilecache code into cgi-bin and now the error was rectified with new error asAn error occurred:

```
File contains no section headers.
file: /var/www/cgi-bin/tilecache-2.11/tilecache.cfg, line: 1
'd# Configuration for MC TileCache\n'
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/tilecache-2.11/TileCache/Service.py", line 85, in _load
    config.read(files)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 305, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 512, in _read
    raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
```

Comment: I'm facing same issue in Linux also.  I followed steps from http://tilecache.org/docs/README.html

Comment: That file is there, tilecache.cfg?You may need something like this, `svc = Service.load("C:\\TileCache\\tilecache.cfg")` but with your path

Comment: Even if i gives the relative path to tilecache.cfg , it displaying the error with the path.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python

from TileCache import Service, cgiHandler, cfgfiles
If I gives the cfg file path the error as follows
if __name__ == '__main__':
    svc = Service.load('/var/www/html/tilecache-2.11/tilecache.cfg')
    cgiHandler(svc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling one week I'm able to configure tilecache in Linux o.s. I also tested alongwith OL3 and working fine. The main problem is that the it is not reading tilecache.cfg files from correct path. So you have to give your absolute path for cfg files wherever required like in tilecache.cgi and services.py files. For mapserver service the mapscript module should be installed.

Answer (score 0):

The [TileCache installation instructions](http://tilecache.org/docs/README.html#running-under-cgi) have one more step:

> Permit CGI execution in the TileCache directory. For example, if TileCache is to be run with Apache, the following must be added in your Apache configuration, where /var/www/tilecache is the directory resulting from the code extraction. On Debian, this is typically /usr/lib/cgi-bin.
>
> ```
> <Directory /var/www/tilecache>
>      AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
>      Options +ExecCGI
> </Directory>
> ```

Comment: This is already included.

Comment: It is included in the Apache configuration that listens on port 80. The server that listens on port 8088 apparently has no such configuration. What is running on 8088? Another Apache? What happens if you change the port to 80 in the URL?

Comment: I have tested changed port also but same problem

Comment: Now it is giving error as, An error occurred: The requested layer () does not exist. Available layers are1: 
 * apdem

Comment: The line `d# Configuration for MC TileCache` does not occur in the file shown in the question.

Comment: After removing the letter 'd' before comment, it is giving the error as , An error occurred: The requested layer () does not exist. Available layers are1: * apdem . But  the command tilecache_ssed.py "layername" 5 18 ran successfully and generated the png files for zoom levels from 5 to 18. Finall iI'm unable to call from browser.

Comment: The pressont problem is , An error occurred: Current x value 77.519531 is too far from tile corner x 77.540864